# custom UITableViewCell accessory not positioned correctly

Tags: position, uitableview

I have 2 custom cell in a grouped style table. The one loaded form xib positions accessory view correctly the one created with storyboard does not, although I think it has more to do with dimensions of the cell. See picture:

EDIT: it is irrelevant if accessory is set in the code or if standard accessory is specified through IB

[image]

Any ideas why this could be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In custom cell overwriting layoutSubviews and doing something like this seems to be fixing the issue.
However I am still not clear and what the x offset is supposed to be adding 10 gets it close, but what is it actually supposed to be? How is offset is calculated based on height of the cell?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.accessoryView.frame.origin.x **+10**,self.accessoryView.frame.origin.y, self.accessoryView.frame.size.width,self.accessoryView.frame.size.height);
}
```